# Psychtoolbox not drawing German Umlauts

Tags: non-ascii-characters, psychtoolbox

I am presenting a German Text in Psychtoolbox. The special characters (Umlauts) are not displaying properly with the DrawText nor DrawFormattedText. The characters are recognized correclty by Matlab when I read in a .txt file to a char cell struct, but Psychtoolbox substututes then the characters with other symbols.
Has anyone solved this issue before?

Comment: What operating system, and version of Psychtoolbox are you using? For example I can draw the text 'Mütter' via DrawFormattedText without issue, on OSX and Psychtoolbox 3.0.14. There is also this information on the Psychtoolbox site related to this potential issue: http://docs.psychtoolbox.org/DrawTextEncodingLocaleSettings

Answer (score 0):

We just found a solution. If the text is stored in the variable "message"

message='öäüßÄÖÜ'

1. Display text by casting message as *uint8()*

**DrawFormattedText(w, *uint8*(message));** % Use uint8() to display Umlaute and other non-ascii signs (UTF-8) by passing as uint8

instead of DrawFormattedText(w, message);** % does not work with Umlaute etc.

2. Use font that displays all characters, e.g. Arial

**Screen('TextFont', w, 'Arial', 1);** % Dont use Helvetica, does not show uppercase ÄÖÜ properly (even after converting it to uint8)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try **Screen('Preference', 'TextEncodingLocale','UTF-8')** to make sure that your text is encoded in UTF-8. I also tried the uint8 solution, which works in one of my work computers but not the other